# How to call a method in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I am just starting out in ios and am trying to make user defined functions...

my code:

```
-(void) testFunction{
    //has self. calls
}

 -(IBAction)button:(id)sender { 
       testFunction();
}
```

I get the warning: Implicit declaration of function is invalid in C99

What am I doing wrong? Or what do I have to add to my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C you cant write `testFunction()`. You send 'messages' and you can do this via

```
[self testFunction]
```